# Material-UI absolute positioning inside a Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to align material-ui icon with text such that the icon's lowest drawn point starts exactly at baseline. We're using Material-UI Grid layout.

The problem is: if I allow the icon to align to 'baseline', it is too high. If I do `alignSelf: 'center'`, it is too low. At this point, I'd be ok with some way of absolute positioning the icon to match text baseline, but I don't know if that's possible with flexbox.

```
  <Grid container justify="space-between" xs={6}>
    <Grid item>
      <Button variant="outlined">Cancel</Button>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item>
      <Grid container alignItems="baseline">
        <Grid item>
          <Grid container alignItems="baseline">
            <Grid item style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
              <Done />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Typography>Done!</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button variant="outlined">Submit</Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</div>
```

As you can see, the icon is rendered below the baseline, while the text is properly aligned:
[image]

[image: Edit elated-cerf-33mme]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom `relative` positioning to manually adjust the position of the checkmark, something like this:

```js
   <Done style={{ position: "relative", top: "-1px"}} />
```

You can change the `top` property until the checkmark is aligned. If you remove the `alignSelf` property, you might need to use `top: "5px"` instead.

Comment: Happy to help ;)